# Clarification of this definition of a closed normed space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, definition

I have come across this definition:

Let $X$ be a normed space and let $Y$ be a subset of $X$. We say that $Y$ is closed in $X$ if, whenever $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a convergent sequence in $X$ such that $x_n\in Y, \forall n\geq 1$, the limit lies in $Y$.

From this definition I don't know how we can say, for example, that $[0,1]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ as the set $\mathbb{R}$ is not a sequence space - $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is. The set $\mathbb{R}$ does not contain sequences so how can this definition be used?

Comment: When we write $x_n$ is a  sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, we mean that $x_n\in\mathbb{R}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, meaning $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}\subset\mathbb{R}$, not $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @GBA very succinct explanation, though the definition above says "$(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a convergent sequence in $X$." Isn't that saying $(x_n)_{1\geq n}\in\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been told in the comments, the expression "$(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a convergent sequence in $X$" means that $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence and that every $x_n$ belongs to $X$. You can consider it is an standard abuse of languaje. You will find lots of them in mathematics.

With this in mind it is easy to prove that $[0,1]$ is closed. Suppose such a sequence with limit $y\notin [0,1]$. You can consider a suitable ball around $y$ and arrive to a contradiction.